# OnLeScan continue firing after bluetooth is switched off

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

It is teoretical question.

One of the customer devices(android 8 htc 10 ) continue firing `OnLeScan` callback after he dissables bluetooth module in settings. He could reproduse it only on  the **htc 10** device.

Steps

1. start app with bluetooth on
2. app discovers beacons
3. swith off bluetooth
4. app continue firing `OnLeScan`

I understand that it is not possible(i can't reproduce it on other devices), but I get this situation.

Now I'm planning disable ble scanning when Bluetooth state is changed, so I think this will help me to fix this problem...

But still I don't understand why it is works like this. Do you have any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think should write some code to stop the leScan.

Try to update a boolean flag like "blutooh_enabled" to keep a watch if the bluetooth is on or off and then write some code i.e,

mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

I think this will help you.

Comment: Yes, I planning to do like this, but not with flag. I already have BroadcastReceiver with IntentFilter BluetoothAdapter.ActionStateChanged. So I will stop scanning there. The main problem, I can't understand why it is working like this

Comment: I understand.Sometimes it creates issue when running on Nexus4 or nexus7.I think you are working with one of those phones.Right?

Comment: I have nexus 5, but it is ok. Only device that cause problems is htc 10